# GCC: Function wrapper template troubles

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, gcc, clang

I am on `GCC 5.3` trying to get some function wrapper code to work which works fine on `clang`. Here is a boiled down example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class Sig, Sig F>
struct FunctionWrapper;


template<class Ret, class... Args, Ret (*Func)(Args...)>
struct FunctionWrapper<Ret(Args...), Func>
{
};

static int testFunc(int _a, int _b)
{
    return _a + _b;
}


int main() {
    FunctionWrapper<int(int, int), testFunc> wrapper;
    return 0;
}
```

The error I get on gcc is the following:

> prog.cpp:9:46: error: 'Ret(Args ...)' is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter
>        struct FunctionWrapper
>                                                 ^
>   prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>   prog.cpp:20:45: error: 'int(int, int)' is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter
>         FunctionWrapper wrapper;

Any ideas about how to make this work on both, `clang` and `gcc`?

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work even in g++6.1

Comment: I think instead of using `Ret(Args...)` directly, you may have more success if you use a typedef for function pointer types when you try to do anything complicated with them. The compilers seem to be confused about reconciling function vs function pointer conversions when matching the template pattern. E.g. `template <class Ret, class... Args> using free_function = Ret(*)(Args...);`

Answer (score 8):

I think this is a gcc bug. According to [temp.param]:

> A non-type template-parameter of type “array of `T`” or of function type `T` is adjusted to be of type “pointer to `T`”.

Having `Ret(Args...)` as a template non-type parameter is equivalent to having `Ret(*)(Args...)` as a template non-type parameter.

Note that gcc does [correctly] compile the following example, which is basically the same idea as your original version:

```
static int testFunc(int _a, int _b)
{
    return _a + _b;
}

template <int F(int, int)>
struct Foo { };


int main() {
    Foo<testFunc> wrapper;
    return 0;
}
```

---

As a workaround, simply forcing the non-type argument to be a pointer is allowed by both compilers:

```
template<class Sig, Sig* F>
struct FunctionWrapper;


template<class Ret, class... Args, Ret (*Func)(Args...)>
struct FunctionWrapper<Ret(Args...), Func>
{ };
```

but I don't believe that this should have been necessary.

Comment: `Having Ret(Args...) as a template non-type parameter... ` should be `Having Ret(Args...) as a template type parameter... ` ?

Comment: @Arunmu No, non-type.

Comment: Yes, gcc is performing the [temp.param] adjustment too early. Example (adapted from temp.param): https://godbolt.org/g/TTXCoU